# connection timeout property in connection string ignored

Tags: c#, timeout, connection-string

I'm building an app in C#. I'm using a connection string like:

```
DSN=SomeDataSource; Trusted Connection=yes; Uid=SomeId; pwd=somePwd; Connection Timeout=x
```

But no matter what value I set as `x` (`Connection Timeout = x`), by putting a breakpoint, I can see that my `DbConnection` object's `ConnectionTimeout` property always has the default value `15`.

Am I missing something here?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to set X higher or lower than 15?  Have you confirmed that it is actuallying timeing out at 15, rather than at X (e.g., perhaps the value you are looking at is a red-herring).  Also, some more code and/or context would be more helpful here (e.g., are you connecting to an Oracle DB, etc.).

Comment: I'm having exactly this problem.  The odd thing is that I added logging to confirm the connection string being used and the time it takes and I'm only getting 9 or 10 seconds instead of the 120 I'm asking for or the 15 that's the default.

Comment: Same thing here. Tried Connect Timeout=5 and Connection Timeout=5.
Both are ignored and it takes 15. Maybe 15 is the minimum??

Comment: did you resolve this issue? Facing similiar problem.

Answer (score 22):

The `Connection Timeout` in the ConnectionString only controls the timeout for the connection.  If you need to increase the wait time on your Commands, use the `CommandTimeout` property of SqlCommand.

Comment: Thank you kindly!

Answer (score 1):

I am not seeing the behvior you are indicating, at least when I test the scenario using a [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

The [ConnectionTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property of the connection matches the [ConnectTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.connecttimeout%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) set on the builder. I used *5*, *20* and *120* as values and all were set on the connection.

using System.Data.SqlClient;

```
var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

builder.ApplicationName     = "My Demo App";
builder.ConnectTimeout      = 5;
builder.DataSource          = "(local)";
builder.InitialCatalog      = "My Database";
builder.IntegratedSecurity  = true;

using(var connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Connection Timeout: {0}", connection.ConnectionTimeout);
}
```

If you are not dealing with SQL, you might also look at using [DbConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnectionstringbuilder%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or one of its sub-types. In general I find it safest to build the connection string programmatically using one of the available builders so that you can avoid any bad formatting of the connection string you will be using to create connections.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, 15 is the minimum, depending on what you're doing.  Probably a per-provider thing.  I've even found when trying to use less than 15 (with some 3rd-party controls) using SQL Native Client, I end up with infinite timeouts instead.  Yuck.  When I set to 15 or higher, it behaves as expected.